# Azure Function Managed Identities and Key Vault Access Poilcy (Chicken Egg Situation)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity

Just wondering whether there is a way to store storage account connection strings in key vault that a function uses. The function is reliant on `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `AzureWebJobsStorage`. I am trying to add these into key vault but the problem I have is..

1. Provision Storage Account
2. Provision Key Vault
3. Provision Function App
4. Add Access Policy for Function to Key Vault

The problem here is, when the function app is created (step 3) it fails as it can't access key vault (missing access policy). I can't create the policy as the function needs to exist.

How have others fixed this? I was thinking of creating the AD Application upfront (step 0) and not use managed identities (which is not ideal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using azure portal to deploy the resources, you could deploy a function app without keyvault reference, then configure the keyvault reference manually.

If you are using ARM template to deploy the resources, the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#azure-resource-manager-deployment) has mentioned your issue.

> Of note, you will need to define your application settings as their own resource, rather than using a `siteConfig` property in the site definition. This is because the site needs to be defined first so that the system-assigned identity is created with it and can be used in the access policy.

Sample:

```
{
    //...
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            //...
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "name": "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
            //...
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            //...
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "config",
                    "name": "appsettings",
                    //...
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'), variables('storageConnectionStringName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'), variables('appInsightsKeyName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('storageConnectionStringResourceId')).secretUriWithVersion, ')')]",
                        "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('storageConnectionStringResourceId')).secretUriWithVersion, ')')]",
                        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[concat('@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=', reference(variables('appInsightsKeyResourceId')).secretUriWithVersion, ')')]",
                        "WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE": "true"
                        //...
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "sourcecontrols",
                    "name": "web",
                    //...
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', variables('functionAppName'), 'appsettings')]"
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
            //...
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                //...
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionAppName'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionAppName'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "secrets": [ "get" ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "secrets",
                    "name": "[variables('storageConnectionStringName')]",
                    //...
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountResourceId'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "secrets",
                    "name": "[variables('appInsightsKeyName')]",
                    //...
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am unclear what the "type": "sourcecontrols" bit does but I removed that and works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem exists for many other resources that need to access Key Vault (including Service Bus, Event Hub, API Management).

How can we create a re-deployable ARM template with these circular dependencies?

Example Deployment of Service Bus With Customer Managed Key Encryption

- Service Bus created without encryption first, since a brand new resource cannot access key vault keys. It gets a managed identity/service principal.
- KeyVault updated to grant access to Service Bus managed identity.
- Service Bus updated with encryption utilizing Key Vault access.
- If the ARM template is re-deployed because infrastructure updates are required, Service Bus re-deployment fails, because encryption cannot be removed
- There is no support for checking if a resource exists already in an ARM template to avoid repeating step 1 on subsequent deployments

User assigned managed identities seems like it could resolve the issue, but they aren't supported in ARM templates!